# 18.04.1 can't boot kernel 4.15.0-30-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, 18.04

I had a stable Ubuntu 18.04 install, but as of this morning it doesn't boot normally. Booting from different kernels gives the following results:

- **4.15.0-30-generic** Boots to a purple screen, which is followed by a black screen.
- **4.15.0-30-generic Recovery Mode** After choosing to continue booting twice in the recovery menu, it runs a start job for the disk partition with my `/home` directory; after 90 seconds, there is a purple screen, followed by a blank screen with a blinking cursor.
- **4.15.0-29-generic** Same as `4.15.0-30-generic`.
- **4.15.0-29-generic** After choosing to 'resume' twice in the recovery menu, it boots normally.

Previous problems suggest that this might be caused by a video driver problem, but I'm not sure. if it is, here's the output from `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:29 memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fb800000-fbbfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:ff00(size=64)
```

I'm using the proprietary `nvidia-driver-390` drivers.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Has the kernel installation finished successfully? Possibly related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1785791